# Guard against invalid page number (0) for will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

The will_pagify gem will_paginate will throw an error if you send it the param `page=0`. Is there a better way than declaring `page = nil (or 1) if param[:page] =~ /^[0]{,}$/`? Hoping this is to support zero-index pages and I can disable this with a function parameter.

*There may be other invalid inputs I haven't tested. Strings go to nil.

**Update:**

Trying to avoid:

```
begin
  model = Model.where(...).paginate(page: params[:page])
  <additional code>
rescue
  model = Model.where(...).paginate(page: '1')
  <redo additional code again or use function***>
```

vs.

```
current_page = clean_page(params[:page])
model = Model.where(...).paginate(page: current_page)
```

Comment: Why not just rescue `WillPaginate::InvalidPage`? This will avoid all the errors you are referring to

Comment: This was going to be my second solution. But this will add more lines, and I hate using exceptions for something I can handle naturally. Although, in this case I think it will be faster not handling corner cases until they're actually needed each time.

Comment: Well your "corner cases" can be found [Here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/page_number.rb#L17) and include `value < 1`, or larger than 9223372036854775807 , and anything that cannot be converted to an Integer via `Kernel#Integer`.

Comment: Probably safest to go with a rescue. Add you answer to accept or delete the post?

Comment: Just now all the code will be: `try pagination (and additional code), rescue, safe paginate, redo additional code from before (that got skipped)` as opposed to `clean paginate, then paginate, rest of code`. See update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage what [`WillPaginate` has already done](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/page_number.rb#L17) to handle all cases as follows:

```
def clean_page(page)
  begin 
    WillPaginate::PageNumber(page)
  rescue WillPaginate::InvalidPage
    1  
  end 
end
```

and that will handle all the same issues because you are leveraging their validation process and anything that fails defaults to page 1.

[Working Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/WillPaginateRescue)

Comment: we can remove the `begin` and second-to-last `end` if using this function as it is.

Comment: @user8897013 you are correct. I am not a big fan of floating rescue statements and would much prefer the encapsulation for readability